# Recalculating IPW after stratification

Tags: survey-weights

This may seem a bit odd as a question.

If one stratifies a dataset using a variable, which was also used in IPW calculation, one will have to recalculate the weight, right?

I am asking because there is a part of me thinking that since it is a binary variable for IPW calculated via logistic regression, all male participants will weigh the same. Therefore, recalculating the weight will be somewhat redundant. Meanwhile, sex was weighted, hence, I should remove it... So the question is, do I need to recalculate the IPW after I divide the data into male-only and female-only? My instinct is yes.

Any thought?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "stratify"? It gets used in different senses

Comment: i.e., divide into two groups: male vs female.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want subpopulation estimates you do not need to recalculate weights.

You do need to [analyse it as a subpopulation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/452112/proper-subsetting-of-survey-data/550867#550867), not just subset the data

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But we may be talking about different things: subset vs subgroup.